# GNOME 13.10 image file

Tags: gnome

I downloaded GNOME 13.10 from [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.10/release/). Is this link trusted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the link in your question is an official Ubuntu webpage where you can find links to download the Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 iso image file for installing Ubuntu GNOME 13.10. The MD5SUMS file found at the top of the list of links on that webpage is a small text file that has the MD5 checksum that is used to verify the Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 iso file after you have downloaded it.

Comment: Always remember that md5sums (and other checksums as well) are **only** for detecting the integrity of the file - e.g did something go wrong while downloading. It alone does not prove that the file is trusted.